# error found :Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am just trying to experiment in a website through inspect elements..when I put the code...I see this error" Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" in this code

```
    var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Sub.length; i++) {
        ctx.drawImage( $("[data-pageid='"+p+"'] .imgKeeper").get(0), data.Sub[i].X1  (s + 16), data.Sub[i].Y1  (s + 16), s, s, data.Sub[i].X2  m, data.Sub[i].Y2  m, m, m);//at this line
    }
```

Please help me ...what should I do?

Comment: `data.Sub[i].X1  (s + 16)` ?  `data.Sub[i].Y2  m` ?

Comment: data.Sub[i].Y1(s+16) is a function. data.Sub[i].X2 m is bulshit , either it is a function and you have to put the m in brackets (m) or its a variable and you have to remove the m

Comment: @G ABBAS What do you expect the output to be ?